# borderColor and borderRadius styles not being applied to a StackLayout

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am trying to create a border-radius and border-color around a StackLayout but for some reason the styles doesn't get applied...  I am using the Nativescript core-light theme, not sure if that can override my inline styles?  Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

my code:

```
        <StackLayout borderRadius="5px" borderColor="blue">         
            <Label class="body" [text]="'Description:  ' + product.Description"></Label>
            <Label class="body" [text]="'POS Description: ' + product.POSDescription"></Label>
            <Label class="body" [text]="'POS price:  R' + product.POSPrice"></Label>
            <Label class="body" [text]="'Stock On Hand:  ' + product.StockOnHand"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set explicitly **borderWidth** and your code will work.
e.g.

```
<StackLayout borderRadius borderWidth="2" borderRadius="15" borderColor="blue">
```

Notice that I am using **DPs** (device independent pixels)  instead of **px** which in the mobile world with different screen densities and resolutions should be the better approach.

You can also use CSS for your borders
e.g.

```
.borders {
    border-width: 2;
    border-color: red;
    border-radius: 20;
}
```